# How to extend and configure an existing WSO2 Event Handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to extend the AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler in order to customize the generate OTP value.

The documentation state how to writing a custom event handler (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-event-handler/), extending the AbstractEventHandler and configuring the new event handler in the deployment.toml configuration file.

What we actually want to achieve is to extend the existing AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler and substitute the current configured AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler with our version, but we don't know what we have to write in the  deployment.toml to substitute the  AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler  instead of adding a new Handler.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following configurations to the `deployment.toml` file.

1. This will remove all the events subscribed by the default adminForcedPasswordReset event handler. Therefore the default handler will not be invoked upon triggering "PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS" and "PRE_AUTHENTICATION" events.

```
[identity_mgt.events.schemes.adminForcedPasswordReset]
subscriptions=[]
```

2. This configuration is to add your custom event handler for AdminForcedPasswordReset. Change the name "customAdminForcedPasswordReset" by whatever the name of your custom event handler. Also, the new handle should subscribe to "PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS" and "PRE_AUTHENTICATION" events.

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "customAdminForcedPasswordReset"
subscriptions=["PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS","PRE_AUTHENTICATION"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the default handler and register your custom handler as below, in the `deployment.toml` file. (I didn't test this though)

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "adminForcedPasswordReset"
subscriptions=["PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS","PRE_AUTHENTICATION"]
enable=false
[[event_handler]]
name= "customAdminForcedPasswordReset"
subscriptions=["PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS","PRE_AUTHENTICATION"]
```

Comment: In this case there a problem:
Adds a new custom event whit module 21 and doesn't put disabled. It also does not replace the existing default event with module 9


# Custom event configuration.
module.name.21=adminForcedPasswordReset
adminForcedPasswordReset.subscription.1=PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS
adminForcedPasswordReset.subscription.2=PRE_AUTHENTICATION
module.name.22=customAdminForcedPasswordReset
customAdminForcedPasswordReset.subscription.1=PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS
customAdminForcedPasswordReset.subscription.2=PRE_AUTHENTICATION